# real-time in context of a game

Tags: real-time, frame-rate

I have a problem grokking the concept of real-time (IMO badly named, different meaning in different contexts). I understand real-time software as a software where time is a key variable. Events must occur at given time. Say, railway switch change at 15:02 and the next one must be at 15:05 no matter what.

But how about this example. In game, when player's FPS drops below 16 game exits and tell user to upgrade his hardware or kill other applications. So when one iteration of the game loop takes more than 1/16 of a second the output of the program is completely different.

Is it real-time(ish)? Can it be considered as a Real Time Computing?

Comment: Are you asking about games in which things like physics, etc. are nondeterministic due to varying step times?

Comment: Eep, I would hope that a game would not just exit mid-game if something (antivirus?) suddenly loaded down my CPU to the point where FPS dropped.

Comment: just an example. I am not making a such thing in a game.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to understand, are you referring to Real Time Computing, or simulating real time, or something completely different?

Simulating real time: It is possible to simulate real-time in a game by polling for events.  Store the time of an event, and then when it comes time to render a frame, the game should repeatedly 'fast forward' by moving the current time to the time of the next event and handle the event.  This should repeat until there are no more events, or the time is 'current'.

This requires you to have anything that is a function of time (such as velocity, position, acceleration) be calculated according to the current time.  This means you would not have these attributes periodically updated, and allows your game to be deterministic, as the 'game time' is no longer dependent upon real time.  It also makes things like game speed and pausing very simple to implement.

If you're referring to the concept of real-time systems, then I would say there's not enough information to determine whether that 'game loop' is 'real-time'.  It depends on the operating environment of the game, and the logic in the 'game loop'.  According to wikipedia, [a real-time deadline must be met, regardless of system load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing).

Comment: Yes, I am referring to game in context real-time computing.

Comment: That's good. Something can live in isolation in properly simulated real-time without knowing whether it is truly real-time, much like an OS can live happily in a VM (in simulated real time) without knowing it's in a VM. How could it, because its simulator doesn't tell it? That supports your function-of-time idea. So I guess it's important to know whether simulated realtime is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the rapidly approaching canonical article [Fix your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/), Glenn Fielder addresses numerous ways to handle this issue.  While the article focuses primarily on physics, the key points are applicable to any system that represents a function of time, to wit, things dealing with moving things.

The executive summary of that article (which is well worth reading) is this:

You can make your physics deterministic (well, as much as can be achieved with imperfect input) by using discrete physics timesteps.  It looks like this:

- Render as fast as possible
- Pass in a time delta that represents how long steps previous took this frame
- Process delta time modulo timestep number of physics steps
- Store the remainder of delta that you weren't able to process in an accumulator

That accumulator gets added to the next frame's time buffer.  This requires some fine tuning such that temporary lag spikes due to e.g. a rapidly spinning player (which necessitates a lot of visibility determination over time) don't end up putting you in an inescapable time debt.  If you wanted to intelligently guard against such an occurrence, you could have a sentry look for dangerous levels of accumulated time, which you could respond to by perhaps dropping a video frame.

Another advantage to using discrete timesteps is that they behave well in multiplayer games.  If you have an authoritative server or node in a peer-to-peer configuration, the server can ensure that all clients' physics simulations are running at the same physics timeline.  Discrete time blocks also simplifies things in rollback based multiplayer.

Edit:

<sub>Disclaimer:  I've never written software for real-time myself, only worked in a company that had!</sub>

In response to really-real real-life Real Time software, it's unlikely that anyone has made a game that could be qualified as this, at least in software.  (I'm not sure how one would qualify games on ROMs or games that don't run under a host OS?)  While your example would be an *attempt* at real-time software, most real-time software goes through a period of certification in which the maximum amount of time spent per instruction or on a logical block of operation is determined.  Games might come close to this in a sense when, for example, platform licensors have requirements (as I believe XBLA does) regarding minimum 30fps or similar.  However, these certifications are usually established through a period of testing rather than through mathematical proof.